# Referencing .NetCore Class Library in .NetCore Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I have created a .NetCore Class Library which I have tested in same solution with .NetCore Console Application (and it works just fine), however when I try referencing it inside another (ASP.NET Core Web Application) solution as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YoutubeExtractorCore/0.0.6) I always get a error

> NU1002 The dependency YoutubeExtractorCore 0.0.6 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

I have added the netcoreapp1.0 in the class library project.json, which looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "YoutubeExtractorCore",
  "description": ".NET Core library used for extracting information about Youtube videos",
  "version": "0.0.6-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I spent this afternoon trying to fix the problem but I cannot even understand why this error occurs.

Comment: are you sure asp.net core app is  using .net core app 1.0 or lesser version?

Comment: @Venky I think it is 1.0, but i am not sure anymore. Anyway, here is ASP.NET Core project.json, targeting the netcoreapp1.0 framework. [link](http://pastebin.com/LSVHmdeN) I added the netstandard1.6 framework too, since I wasn't sure if it is needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what was causing the problem. The NuGet package I created was packed with `nuget.exe` manually, and for some reason did not have the frameworks and their dependencies listed. I fixed the package by executing `dotnet pack` on the class library and this produced correcly packed NuGet package.